# Angular SSR -File to import not found or unreadable:

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

In my `angular.json > projects > landing > architect > built > options` I have:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/theme/mixins"
  ]
},
```

which let me import the styles in the components' style like:

```
@import "breakpoints"; // instead of ../../../../theme/mixins/breakpoints
```

The problem starts when I want to build the app for `server`. Since I can't add `stylePreprocessorOptions` to the architect built options for the server, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import "breakpoints";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoints.
```

When I try to add `stylePreprocessorOptions` to the `server` architecture, I get the following error:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "['server']" should NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "['server']" should NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).
```

While changing the path relatively, it works:

```
@import "../../../../theme/mixins/breakpoints";
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I have the same problem. I use angular 9 and i cannot find any reason while this shouldnt be working.